# Пунктуация при однородных членах предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Наклонившись, долго выковыривал я гайку пальцем и, сидя на корточках, счищал и сдувал с нее песчинки. Так у Гайдара в "Судьбе барабанщика". Если опираться на правила постановки знаков препинания в предложениях с однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимися союзами, то запятых в этом предложении должно быть на две больше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наклонившись, долго **выковыривал** я гайку пальцем и, сидя на корточках, (**счищал и сдувал**) с нее песчинки. Это схема   1 + 2   для трёх однородных членов. За первым действием "выковыривал" следуют два связанных по смыслу действия очистки (счищал и сдувал).

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Три однородных члена могут соединяться  двумя союзами И (ДА=И) по схеме  1 + 2, когда один союз И соединяет тесно связанную ПО СМЫСЛУ пару однородных членов, а затем другой союз И соединяет эту пару с третьим однородным членом.

Таким образом, при наличии двух союзов И запятая между однородными членами не ставится.

Следует обратить внимание, что перечислительная интонация при этом отсутствует .

Практические примеры

А) Запятая НЕ СТАВИТСЯ (тесное единство двух однородных членов, нет перечислительной интонации):

Он прошёл (огонь и воду) и медные трубы. На огромном расстоянии разлёгся город  и (тихо пламенел и сверкал разноцветными огнями).И стали они (жить да поживать)  да добра наживать.

Б) Запятая СТАВИТСЯ (нет тесного единства двух однородных членов, перечислительная интонация): Листья в поле пожелтели, и кружатся, и летят.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нет двух "и" при однородных членах: первое "и" служит для присоединения двух действий, выполняемых при закреплённом отдельно за ними обстоятельстве образа действия "сидя на корточках". Если его убрать и привести всё к "однородности", то лучше убрать и первое "и", иначе получится излишне сентиментально:

```
Я выковыривал гайку, и чистил её, и сдувал с неё песчинки.
```

Answer (score 2):

[См.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=124#pp124):

> **§ 13…**  Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом ***и***, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом ***и*** с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится: *…Задолго до рассвета Ильинична затопила печь и к утру уже выпекла хлеб и насушила
>   две сумы сухарей* (Ш.) — парная группа ***выпекла и насушила*** с общим
>   обстоятельством времени ***к утру***.

В Вашем случае сказуемые ***счищал и сдувал***  имеют не только общее обстоятельство образа действия, выраженное деепричастным оборотом, но и общее прямое дополнение -- ***песчинки***. И потому даже при отсутствии деепричастного оборота дополнительных запятых это предложение не требовало бы.

Answer (score 1):

Никак нет. *Выковыривал и (счищал и сдувал)* – такая схема.